# No rendertargets set in RenderPassDescriptor

Tags: ios, metal

The signal SIGABRT error:

```
validateRenderPassDescriptor:611: failed assertion
`No rendertargets set in RenderPassDescriptor.'
```

This is how I set up the MTLRenderPassDescriptor:

```
guard let currenDrawable: CAMetalDrawable = self.currentDrawable else { return }

let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = currenDrawable.texture
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)            

let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
```

The crash occurs when I call makeRenderCommandEncoder().

Anyone know how to avoid a crash, to check if rendertargets are not present and abort?

Comment: Presumably, `currenDrawable.texture` is `nil`.

Comment: currenDrawable.texture appears not to be optional, tho is see some allocated memory property, maybe I'll check that

Comment: @Hexagons we also encounter this crash. did you find how to avoid this?

Comment: @kkpattern I can't say for sure, it was a while ago. I did get passed it. It might have been a bad beta of Xcode. You can reference the working code here (around line 175): https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/master/Source/PixelsRender.swift

Answer (score 1):

Must initialize `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0]` before using it.
Just add `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0] = MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor();`